# How to show meetings from a specific calendar (from multiple calendars of Evolution) in Ubuntu calendar?

Tags: email, evolution, calendar, 22.04

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and have set up my office's mail in the Evolution mail client (version 3.44.0-1). As my office uses Exchange Web Services (EWS), I can subscribe to my colleagues' calendars so that I have **multiple calendars** in my **Evolution mail client**.

The **problem** I am facing is that **all the meetings from all the calendars** of Evolution **are being shown in my Ubuntu calendar**.

[image: Calendar]

However, I would like to see the meetings **only from my calendar** (from Evolution) in **my Ubuntu calendar**.

Does anybody know a workaround to achieve this?